# How do I center my buttons in specific columns of my choosing in my dojo GridX?

Tags: css, button, dojo, dijit.form, dojo.gridx

I was able to center the text within the header, using this:

```
[colid="startstop"].gridxCell{ 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

I thought this would center all row cells belonging to the startstop column, but it doesn't. My startstop column contains a single button in each row. I have two other columns just like this. How do I center the buttons in the three columns of my choosing?

Here is a peice of my structure:

```
                     { id: 'startstop', field: 'startstop', name: 'Start/Stop', width: '61px', 
                        widgetsInCell: true, 
                        navigable: true, 
                        allowEventBubble: true, 
                        decorator: function(){ 
                                //Generate cell widget template string 
                                return [ 
                                        '<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" ', 
                                        'data-dojo-attach-point="btn" ', 
                                        'class="startStopButton" ', 
                                        'data-dojo-props= ', 
                                        '"onClick: function(){', 
                                                'alert(\'Start/Stop\');', 
                                        '}"><img src="images/1413390026_control.png" /></button>' 
                                ].join(''); 
                        }, 
                        setCellValue: function(data){ 
                                //"this" is the cell widget 
                                this.btn.set('label', data); 
                        } 
                    },
```

Here is my css class - it only does the size of the button for now as I am having other troubles getting it to work by itself - but that's another question.

```
.startStopButton .dijitButtonNode {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I put a <div> around the decorator, but I'm not sure if this is the most correct way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include widgets in a cell, it is recommended to use the `widgetsInCell` flag, along with the `onCellWidgetCreated` and `setCellValue` methods (as documented [here](https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/How-to-show-widgets-in-gridx-cells%3F)).

Here is how I use a cell with a horizontal slider:

```js
{
  id: 'scoreColId',
  field: 'score',
  name: 'Score',
  width: '15%',

  // flag there are widgets in cell so that they are destroyed when grid is destroyed
  widgetsInCell: true,

  // method to create the widget (no cell-specific data yet)
  onCellWidgetCreated: function(cellWidget, column) {
    // outer div to center align the widget inside placed in the cell
    var outerDiv = domConstruct.create('div', {
      style: {
        'text-align': 'center'
      }
    }, cellWidget.domNode);

    // create the widget and place it in the div (already inside the cell)
    cellWidget.slider = new HorizontalSlider({
      minumum: 0,
      maximum: 10,
    });
    cellWidget.slider.placeAt(outerDiv);
  },

  // set each cell with it's specific data
  setCellValue: function(gridData, storeData, cellWidget) {
    var score = gridData.docScore;
    cellWidget.slider.set('value', score);
  }
},
```